# Unsure about this usage of か

Tags: grammar, particle-か, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

I recently encountered this sentence:

> 床には血痕が残っている。**かなり時間が経つのか**血が固まっている。

I believe I understand that the second part is saying the blood is dry (or has hardened) because quite some time has passed. I'm not sure what the か after 経つの is doing -- is the speaker not quite sure if that's the right explanation (something like, "The blood has hardened, perhaps because a lot of time has passed")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your explanation is right.

The speaker is not quite sure if that's the right explanation (something like, "The blood has hardened, perhaps because a lot of time has passed").

The grammar you are looking for is defined in [this page](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34861/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B/), which says:

> 疑いの気持ちで推定する意を表す