# やることが多過ぎて気が張っているせいか

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

多過ぎ - too much

て - Why is it there? What's its position relating the grammar?

気 - Does it express intention? What does it represent exactly?

張って - to fill, to do maybe?

いるせいか - What is the grammatical function of this??

I'm a N4 Japanese learner so it's still so confusing for me to resolve the sentences. Can someone analyze it?? Thank you so much for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 多過ぎる works as an intransitive **verb**, and 多すぎて is its te-form. This te-form describes a reason/cause. Recheck the grammar of ～過ぎる.
- [気が張る](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%8C%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase that means "to feel nervous", "one's nerve is stretched". 気が張っている is its progressive form.
- せい is a special noun (形式名詞) which translates to "due to", "because of". (This seems to be [categorized](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84-sei-%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7-seide-%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B-seika/) as a N3 grammar point, but it's very common in colloquial Japanese.)
- This か is a question marker, but in this context it's like "presumably", "possibly" or "supposedly". See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65697/5010).

> やることが多過ぎて気が張っているせいか
>   possibly due to the fact that [someone] is being nervous because there are too many things to do

Comment: Thank you so much for this satisfying answer. But it keeps me wondering, isn't the seika is a little redundant? I mean there's already ''て'' giving me the cause/reason, right?

Comment: @translatorwitch There are two levels of cause/effect relationships. One is "having a lot of work and thus being nervous" (described by the te-form). The other is "being nervous and thus ～", where this ～ refers to what comes after せいか. So what's the remaining part of your sentence?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I thought seika was linked to the first sentence.

Here it is:

毎日やることが多過ぎて気が張っているせいか、眠ってもすぐに目覚めてしまう。
They are nervous so they wake up right away?

Comment: @translatorwitch Yes, they cannot sleep well, and that's perhaps because they are nervous, and that's because they have a lot of tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help, really.