# Is ためか the same as ために?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-か

I think this sentence:

> あまり日がささまいためか、どれもひょろひょろとした貧弱な木だ

means something like "Since they get too much sunlight, they are shabby trees", but while I know `ために` I can't find anything about `ためか` in my grammars; I was wondering if they have the same meaning.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65694/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29878/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60298/5010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ためか and ために don't mean the same thing -- just as か and に do not mean the same thing.

The か in ためか is the same か used as the verbal question mark.  This indicates uncertainty and indefiniteness.

*(Separately, I'm pretty sure you have a typo, where ささまい should be ささない instead.)*

If the sentence said あまり日がささないため[に]{●}, that would be a definite reason.  However, the sentence instead says あまり日がささないため[か]{●}, indicating that the speaker is uncertain, and is proposing a possible theoretical reason for the observed result.  In English, we would use words like *maybe*, *perhaps*, *possibly*, and the like to express a similar idea.

Comment: You could be right on the typo: I wasn't able to find the phrase in the text, so I went with what I wrote down, but when I first translated it by memory I translated `あまり` as "not much", which means I was remembering a negative verb afterwards.