# What does のでしょうか do here?

Tags: grammar, usage

An assistant is talking about how they are reminded of their time being Margret's assistant when they come back to her old room. I can't figure out how to parse のでしょうか. It doesn't seem like they are asking a question. It reads like a statement with のでしょうか tagged onto the end.

> 回廊を歩き、孤児院長室の前に立つと、前孤児院長マルグリット様の側仕えであった頃の感覚に戻ってしまうのでしょうか。

Comment: Source: https://ncode.syosetu.com/n4830bu/171/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a question addressed to the speaker themselves. The question marker か adds a sense of uncertainty to the corresponding verb, 戻ってしまう. The の before でしょう is an explanatory-no, but 戻ってしまう is serving as a reason of the **next** sentence.

> 回廊を歩き、孤児院長室の前に立つと、前孤児院長マルグリット様の側仕えであった頃の感覚に戻ってしまうのでしょうか。孤児院長の部屋の前で自分が来訪のベルを鳴らすのが、未だに不思議な気がいたします。
>
> Walking down the corridor and standing in front of the Director's room — is this because I find myself slipping back into the time when I was in service to the former Director, Lady Margret? — I still find it strange to ring the bell myself in front of the Director's room.

As shown above, you may think these two sentences are fundamentally one big sentence, where the か-clause is serving as a reason of the following part.

Related:

- [Unsure about this usage of か](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29878/5010)
- [How to use ~のか accurately? 「体調が悪いのか、顔色があまり良くない。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60298/5010)
- [What does からか mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65694/5010)